# YouTube api does not apply quota extension, quota still limited to 10k

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I got new YouTube quotas approved. But there is one problem. They do not work. It appears to me that there are actually two of them. In fact, there are new quotas, but they are not.
What could it be and how can I get out of this situation? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay you got me on this one.  Let me ping someone at Google for you.  (Email sent, wait and see.)

Comment: Please send me a pm on Twitter if you can I have heard back from the team.   I can't post the response here though

Comment: @DaImTo give me your twitter

https://twitter.com/LindaLawtonDK?

Comment: I have forwarded your info. You may want to delete that email address before you get a lot of spam.

Comment: There is a second question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72883276/1841839) with the same issue.  I think YouTube has an issue still waiting to hear back they are looking into it.

Comment: There is a third question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/72984919/1841839

Answer (score 1):

Currently this appears to be an internal issue with the YouTube API.

When you get a quota extension, either the old 10k quota should either be removed or the new higher quota should be the one applied when you are making requests.

There appears to be a bug some where in the system.  where you have two quotas and only the lower one is being applied and the higher one is being ignored.

I am in contact with the team and they are looking into it.  I have not heard anything positive back yet only that they are still trying to diagnose the issue.

I'm going placing this as an answer here as it was the first question regarding this issue.  I can close vote all other questions as duplicate to this one.  There by keeping everything in one place.

Currently there are four.

- [YouTube api does not apply quota extension, quota still limited to 10k](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72816785/1841839)
- ['defaultPerDayPerProject' to 'default/CLIENT_PROJECT-1d'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72883276/1841839)
- [Youtube data API not using the correct quota](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72984919/1841839)
- [Why am I getting quota exceeded with enough quota remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73003145/1841839)

There is also a report on the issue forum

- [Quota Increase Not Working](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/237963675)

Comment: I heard back from the team that this should be fixed.

Comment: The issue has been finally fixed