# 'defaultPerDayPerProject' to 'default/CLIENT_PROJECT-1d'

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

[image]

How to use 'default/CLIENT_PROJECT-1d' quota limit instead of 'defaultPerDayPerProject' in https://console.cloud.google.com/ project for youtube data API v3.

Comment: Can you take a picture of your quotes and tell me what you mean by default/CLIENT_PROJECT-1d

Comment: I attached the image in my question. pls checked.

Comment: default/CLIENT_PROJECT-1d  quotes the additional limit provided by the google team.

Comment: Okay hang in there, you are the second one with this issue.  Here is the first  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72816785/1841839)  Im just going to send YouTube devs a link to your question as well.

Comment: Have you found any solution @DalmTo?

Comment: No I dont currently.  It seams it may be an issue with YouTube.  I contacted the team about the previous question I linked and they are looking into it.  Yesterday I sent them a a link to your question.   Your only option currently is to wait until they fix it.   I will let you know if / when i hear back from the team.

Comment: Ok, I will be waiting until you get a reply to the youtube team, when you get an update please update me asap. Thank you @DaImTo

Comment: You may want to just try once a day or something.  Sometimes they fix stuff and dont get back to me.

Comment: I am trying it last 20 days. I got every day's same error "quota limit exceeds"

Comment: I only sent the report in this week.  

Comment: Any update from the google team @DalmTo?

Comment: Nothing but its summer now and they may be on vacation.  I would test it every now and then see if they fix it.

Comment: There is a third question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/72984919/1841839

Comment: Fourth One here https://stackoverflow.com/q/73003145/19561081

Comment: Any update from the google team @DalmTo?

Comment: Google Team delete my approved extension quota @DalmTo.