# Why am I getting quota exceeded with enough quota remaining

Tags: python, api, google-api, youtube, youtube-api

I am developing an app locally and I had integrated `YouTube Data API V3`.
I had also requested additional quota which was accepted and I have some extra quota with me now.

However, I am still hitting the limit pretty quickly and the additional quota that I have is not being used. The quota is still being limited to 10,000. Can someone tell me why the additional quota that I have got is not being used.

[image: Problem Img]

Do I have to change something in the code to use the additional quota
-> I am using python (`googleapiclient`)

Comment: Seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72984919/youtube-data-api-not-using-the-correct-quota

Comment: There are now a total of four questions relating to this issue.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/72816785/1841839
https://stackoverflow.com/q/72883276/1841839
https://stackoverflow.com/q/72984919/1841839
https://stackoverflow.com/q/73003145/1841839    I have sent your issue to the YouTube team.

Comment: You can add https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73075049/youtube-api-is-using-the-old-quota-the-quota-before-i-got-approved-for-more to your list